# Rename File to Eliminate Date & Time using Python

Tags: python

I have file name “xyz_submission 060921-1516 copy060921-1516”

I need a code to eliminate the above file name is such a way that the file name should become “xyz_submission”.

Pls suggest.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know What you are asking, but if you want to rename a file you can do this.

```py
import os
os.rename('xyz_submission 060921-1516 copy060921-1516','xyz_submission')
```

If the xyz_submission 060921-1516 copy060921-1516 is a .py file or a .txt file or some other file, you will need to add on the ending.

Edited

If you want to take away the date and time for all of them you could do this.(This only works when a space separates the date and time from what you want to keep, and its the first space in the file name.)

```py
import os
files = ['xyz_submission 060921-1516 copy060921-1516','xyz_submission 2345721-12316 copy062421-12316']
number = 0
for file in files:
  new_file = file.split(' ',1)[0]
  os.rename(str(file),str(new_file)+str(number))
  number = number+1
```

When I did this I got Two files, one named xyz_submission0 and the other named xyz_submission1.
the number at the end of the file is to prevent them from becoming one same file.

Comment: Thx, but the file names are all different. For example: 1010xyz_submission and then date & time. So, need a unique code to just remove the date and time and keep the file name as is. Thx